# Unable to install cairo

Tags: python, animation, msys, pycairo

I am trying to animate 2 svg file. for this i need cairo so I have isntalled MSYS2 I have run command on the system

```bash
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-gobject
```

but still getting the error that no library caller cario was found

```
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'
```